# Windows Phone 7 access Azure Mobile Service (The remote server returned an error: not found)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I try to create a new mobile service from Azure, 
and the data has been correctly exposed by Json.

https://lifehope.azure-mobile.net/tables/USERPF

USERPF is a sample table.

In order to simplify the question, I just modified the permission to "everyone".

The problems is the code listed below doesn't work.
Error message is: **the remote server returned an error: not found**
when I hit the Insert button to insert a new record in USERPF...

```
    private void butInsert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        USERPF item = new USERPF();
        item.Column1 = 789;
        item.Column2 = 789;

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        //wc.Headers["X-ZUMO-APPLICATION"] = "";
        wc.UploadStringCompleted += (ss, arg) =>
        {
            if (arg.Error == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("OK");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(arg.Error.Message);
            }
        };

        wc.UploadStringAsync(
            new Uri("https://lifehope.azure-mobile.net/tables/USERPF/"),
            "POST", JsonHelper.ObjectToJson(item, typeof(USERPF)));
    }
```

//USERPF.cs

```
public class USERPF
{
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.IgnoreDataMember()]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember()]
    public int Column1 { get; set; }
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember()]
    public int Column2 { get; set; }
}
```

//JsonHelper.cs

```
    public static string ObjectToJson(object obj, Type type)
    {
        try
        {
            //Create a stream to serialize the object to.
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            // Serializer the User object to the stream.
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(type);
            ser.WriteObject(ms, obj);
            byte[] json = ms.ToArray();
            ms.Close();
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(json, 0, json.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending JSON data, but you're saying that it's of a different content type:

```
wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

Set the correct content-type in the request:

```
wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
```

Something unrelated: if your type isn't decorated with `[DataContract]`, you don't need to decorate the properties Column1 and Column2 with `[DataMember]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast `arg.Erro`r to `WebException`, and check the Statuce code. It might be 401 (Unauthorized)

```
 var webException = arg.Error as WebException;
 if(webException == null) return;


   if (webException.Response != null)
   { 
     var response = (HttpWebResponse)webException.Response; 
     var status  = response.StatusCode; //press F9 here
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried opening and closing the authorization...the results are the same: **StatusCode:0 "Badrequest"**